# Flutter future json list define as a final and stop updating it

Tags: flutter, dart

I could fetch the JSON response from the server and make a list. Now I wanted to add a filter to that list.

To do so, I followed an online tutorial. in that tutorial, the "duplicateItems" variable has created as final. See the code:

```
final duplicateItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");
var items = List<String>();
```

but in my case, as I'm using Future method to get the list from a server, I can't or I don't know to make that variable as final. See the code:

```
class _ListServiceProvidersState extends State<ListServiceProviders> {  
  List items;
  List duplicateItems;  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSharedValues();
  }

  getSharedValues() async {
    bool value = await sharedPreferenceService.getSharedPreferencesInstance();
    if (value) {
      token = await sharedPreferenceService.token;
      fetchServices();
    } else {
      commonModelServices.showMessage(
          'You must log in before use the services', _scaffoldKey, Colors.red);
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        '/LoginPage',
      );
    }
  }

  Future<String> fetchServices() async {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      commonModelServices.onLoading(context);
    });
    final response = await http.get(
        'API URL?category_id=$catId&city=$cityId&latitude=$latitude&longitude=$longitude');
    setState(() {
      commonModelServices.offLoading(context);
      var resBody = json.decode(response.body);
      if (resBody['success'] == true) {
        setState(() {
          duplicateItems = resBody['data']['data'];
          items = duplicateItems;
        });
      }
    });
    return "Success";
  }
```

This is my filtering function

```
  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List dummySearchList = List();
    print('Original List');
    dummySearchList.addAll(duplicateItems);
    print(dummySearchList);
    print('Search Query');
    print(query);
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      print('search query not empty');
      List dummyListData = List();
      print('Start of the loop');
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        print('List single item');
        print(item);
        if (item['name'].contains(query)) {
          print('Item contain search query');
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      print('End of the loop');
      setState(() {
        print('Clear duplicated List');
        items.clear();
        print('Set searched results');
        items.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      print('Search query empty');
      setState(() {
        print('Clear prevoius searched in duplicate list');
        items.clear();
        print('Add Original List to duplicate');
        items.addAll(duplicateItems);
      });
    }
  }
```

The filter works as expected for the first letter in the search field. but then for the next key press, when the filterSearchResults function execute, the original List also get updated to the searched result of the first key press. So it search the search term from the previous searched results but not from the Original List. So, the result is wrong.

I want to keep the original Variable "duplicateItems" unchanged after a search.

Can you tell me what is missing here?

For your information, I'll put the full code below.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_healthcare_app/src/theme/extention.dart';
import 'package:flutter_healthcare_app/src/theme/light_color.dart';
import 'package:flutter_healthcare_app/src/theme/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter_healthcare_app/src/theme/theme.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_healthcare_app/src/model/shared_pref_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_healthcare_app/src/model/common_model.dart';

class ListServiceProviders extends StatefulWidget {
  ListServiceProviders({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListServiceProvidersState createState() => _ListServiceProvidersState();
}

class _ListServiceProvidersState extends State<ListServiceProviders> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  SharedPreferenceService sharedPreferenceService = SharedPreferenceService();
  CommonModel commonModelServices = CommonModel();
  List items;
  List duplicateItems;
  String token;
  String cityId;
  int catId;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSharedValues();
  }

  getSharedValues() async {
    bool value = await sharedPreferenceService.getSharedPreferencesInstance();
    if (value) {
      token = await sharedPreferenceService.token;
      cityId = await sharedPreferenceService.cityId;
      catId = await sharedPreferenceService.catId;
      latitude = await sharedPreferenceService.latitude;
      longitude = await sharedPreferenceService.longitude;
      fetchServices();
    } else {
      commonModelServices.showMessage(
          'You must log in before use the services', _scaffoldKey, Colors.red);
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        '/LoginPage',
      );
    }
  }

  Future<String> fetchServices() async {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      commonModelServices.onLoading(context);
    });
    final response = await http.get(
        'API URL?category_id=$catId&city=$cityId&latitude=$latitude&longitude=$longitude');
    setState(() {
      commonModelServices.offLoading(context);
      var resBody = json.decode(response.body);
      if (resBody['success'] == true) {
        setState(() {
          duplicateItems = resBody['data']['data'];
          items = duplicateItems;
        });
      }
    });
    return "Success";
  }

  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List dummySearchList = List();
    print('Original List');
    dummySearchList.addAll(duplicateItems);
    print(dummySearchList);
    print('Search Query');
    print(query);
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      print('search query not empty');
      List dummyListData = List();
      print('Start of the loop');
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        print('List single item');
        print(item);
        if (item['name'].contains(query)) {
          print('Item contain search query');
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      print('End of the loop');
      setState(() {
        print('Clear duplicated List');
        items.clear();
        print('Set searched results');
        items.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      print('Search query empty');
      setState(() {
        print('Clear prevoius searched in duplicate list');
        items.clear();
        print('Add Original List to duplicate');
        items.addAll(duplicateItems);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: commonModelServices.appBar(context),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: _header(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  filterSearchResults(value);
                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: AppTheme.fullHeight(context),
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return _categoryListView(index, items, context);
                    })),
          ],
        )));
  }

  Widget _header() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Categories", style: TextStyles.titleM),
      ],
    ).p16;
  }

/*  Widget _doctorsList(index, data, context) {

  }*/

  Widget _categoryListView(index, model, context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(4, 4),
            blurRadius: 10,
            color: LightColor.grey.withOpacity(.2),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(-3, 0),
            blurRadius: 15,
            color: LightColor.grey.withOpacity(.1),
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 8),
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          leading: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13)),
            child: Container(
              height: 55,
              width: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: randomColor(),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(model[index]['image'].toString()),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              /*child: Image.asset(
                model[index]['image'].toString(),
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),*/
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(model[index]['name'], style: TextStyles.title.bold),
          subtitle: Text(
            model[index]['description'],
            style: TextStyles.bodySm.subTitleColor.bold,
          ),
          trailing: Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
            size: 30,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
      ).ripple(() {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/DetailPage", arguments: model);
      }, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
    );
  }

  void _showCategoryListPage(selectedCategory, catId, context) {
    sharedPreferenceService.setCatId(catId);
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      '/SelectServiceProvider',
    );
  }

  Color randomColor() {
    var random = Random();
    final colorList = [
      Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      LightColor.orange,
      LightColor.green,
      LightColor.grey,
      LightColor.lightOrange,
      LightColor.skyBlue,
      LightColor.titleTextColor,
      Colors.red,
      Colors.brown,
      LightColor.purpleExtraLight,
      LightColor.skyBlue,
    ];
    var color = colorList[random.nextInt(colorList.length)];
    return color;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should make use of streamBuilder for the list. Stream is changable state, Future is once and for all, u can read an awesome tutorial here: https://medium.com/@sidky/using-streambuilder-in-flutter-dcc2d89c2eae

Comment: @xion The UI is updating according to what I search. If I type "a" it filters the list and show only the list items having "a", the problem starts with the second character. When I type "aa" then it search "aa" from the result list of "a" that happens because both of the "items" and "duplicateItems" variables are getting update after each search. That is the issue I want to solve. It must update only "items" variable keeping "duplicateItems" as same as always

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer in the google flutter community. I'm sharing it here for the future use of someone else.

there is only one line to update.

As I just do this

```
setState(() {
      duplicateItems = resBody['data']['data'];
      items = duplicateItems;
    });
```

it only makes a reference variable. So when I update the items variable it automatically updates the duplicateItems variable as well.

so I have to update that like below. So both are working as two different lists.

```
duplicateItems = List.from(items);
```

So full code is like below.

```
setState(() {
  commonModelServices.offLoading(context);
  var resBody = json.decode(response.body);
  if (resBody['success'] == true) {
    setState(() {
      items = resBody['data']['data'];
    });
  }
  //items = duplicateItems;
  duplicateItems = List.from(items);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was happening to me as to you. Matching variables is referencing them with each other, not copying their data. Thank you very much for posting your solution.

I had

```
items = jsonResponse.data;
duplicateItems = items;
```

That references the items variable but doesn't copy the data.

What is correct is what you say

```
items = jsonResponse.data;
duplicateItems = List.from(items);
```

So the filter works.

The original tutorial is

https://karthikponnam.medium.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685

Thank you very much for posting your solution.
Solution *elementary dear Watson*